# How do I change the environment in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I just started using CakePHP for a small project. I have rails experience, and I can see Cake and Rails are really similar, but I can't seem to find where to change the environment in which you are working. How can I do so? I'm currently working with test because I want to see all those debugging messages, but I want to see how the final design looks and I need to get rid of those messages. How can I change the environment to production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the debug level in app/core/config.php, and set it to 0 (production mode).